# Java match the same group multiple times

Tags: java, regex

I need to match in a sequence of characters the same pattern multiple times.

Eg: For the input `Some words <firstMatch> some words <secondMatch> some more words <ThirdMatch>` I would need `<firstMatch>`, `<secondMatch>`, `<thirdMatch>`

I have tried something like this:

```
String input = "Some words <firstMatch> some words <secondMatch> some more words <ThirdMatch>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( ".*(\\<.*\\>).*" );
Matcher m = pattern.matcher( input );
while ( m.find() ) {
         System.out.println( m.group( 1 ) );
}
```

All I get is `ThirdMatch`

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why does your pattern fail?**

`.*(\\<.*\\>).*` invloves a lot of backtracking. First, `.*` matches any 0+ chars other than linebreak characters, basically the whole line. Then, the regex engine backtracks trying to accommodate for the subsequent pattern, `(<.*>).*`. When it finds the `<` (first from the end), it will again grab the whole line, and will go on backtracking searching for the `>`. Once found, the last `.*` just matches the rest of the line. Note that if the engine fails to find that `>` after `<`, backtracking will  repeat the  search, making this pattern rather inefficient. Note: `<` and `>` do not have to be escaped in a Java regex pattern, they are not special regex metacharacters.

**Solution**

Use a simpler `"<[^>]*>"` pattern based on a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
String input = "Some words <firstMatch> some words <secondMatch> some more words <ThirdMatch>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "<[^>]*>" );
Matcher m = pattern.matcher( input );
while ( m.find() ) {
   System.out.println( m.group(0) ); // = m.group(), the whole match value
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Xt0Rzz)

The `<[^>]*>` will match `<`, 0+ chars other than `>`, and then `>`. Since you are using `Matcher#find()` in a `while` block, you will find all non-overlapping matches in the input string, but you need to access `.group(0)` (equal to `.group()`, the whole match value), not `.group(1)`.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto: Yes, it will work, too. I just want to be explicit here, to show OP that it is necessary to access the whole match here. I edited the answer to explain that bit.

Comment: It works, but can you please explain what do those square brackets mean?

Comment: I added some more explanations. Basically, that is a *negated character class* that you may enhance like `[^<>]` to match any char other than `<` and `>`.

Comment: I just read about negated classes and understood it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expression

```
[^<]*<([^>]*)>
```

**Test String**

```
Some words <firstMatch> some words <secondMatch> some more words <ThirdMatch>
```

**Match String**

```
Match 1
Group 1.    12-22   `firstMatch`
Match 2
Group 1.    36-47   `secondMatch`
Match 3
Group 1.    66-76   `ThirdMatch`
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sPsFor/1)

Answer (score 1):

`.*` is [greedy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) - it will match everything it can up to the final match for the next pattern...  You can make it non-greedy by adding a question mark after the `*` symbol so matching any character, any number of times, not greedy would be `.*?` and your pattern would be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( ".*?(\\<.*\\>).*?" );
```

However this only gets you halfway there.  If you are aware of how many times your pattern willl be matched you can just put that into your pattern e.g.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(  ".*?(\\<.*\\>).*?(\\<.*\\>).*?(\\<.*\\>).*?" );
```

for three matches.

Answer (score 1):

There you go :)

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\<[^\\>\\<]+\\>)");`